# PHP SIGSEGV issue when xdebug is ON

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm using Docker for may local development.
Stack is; php-fpm 8.1.26, nginx, Laravel 10 and PhpStorm 2023.3.1
A strange problem occurred today. So far everything was working fine. But today when I run xdebug the application suddenly ends the process.

```
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:34] WARNING: [pool www] child 9 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 127.958617 seconds from start
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:34] NOTICE: [pool www] child 11 started
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:36] WARNING: [pool www] child 10 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 129.519516 seconds from start
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:36] NOTICE: [pool www] child 12 started
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:38] WARNING: [pool www] child 11 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 4.094282 seconds from start
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:38] NOTICE: [pool www] child 13 started
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 12 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 22.402854 seconds from start
   | [21-Dec-2023 09:44:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 14 started
```

With xdebug disabled, everything works fine.

Xdebug itself seems to work properly. I can set breakpoints in the index.php file and in the files that start Laravel. The request goes to index.php and then everything is processed correctly, the application is initialised, the services are registered, etc. But then at some point the process stops.

This is my config Dockerfile:

```
server {
    listen 8001 default_server;
    listen [::]:8001 default_server;
    server_name ${NGINX_HOST};

    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php_centralised_app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # All static files will be served directly.
    location ~* /(styles|images|scripts|storage)/ {
        location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 1y;

            ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
            ## fell swoop.
            tcp_nodelay off;

            ## Set the OS file cache.
            open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
            open_file_cache_valid 45s;
            open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
            open_file_cache_errors off;
        }
    }

    # We don't need .ht files with nginx.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        return  301 /;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
FROM php:8.1.26-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        nano \
        libxslt1.1 \
        libxslt1-dev \
        unzip \
        git \
        gnupg \
        libpq-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        iputils-ping \
        supervisor \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    gd \
    mysqli pdo pdo_mysql  \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl

# Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log='/tmp/xdebug.log'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "max_input_vars='10000'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extra.ini \
    && echo "" >> /tmp/xdebug.log

    #create user "laravel" and give them permission to write xdebug files. The same user is used to run container on the end file
RUN addgroup --gid 1000 laravel
RUN adduser --ingroup laravel --shell /bin/sh laravel

RUN chown laravel:laravel /tmp/xdebug.log
RUN chmod 777 /tmp/xdebug.log

RUN echo "memory_limit='512M'" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-extra.ini;

ENV PHP_IDE_CONFIG "serverName=threat_match_central_app"

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer --version=2.3.8 && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer

# Set timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime \
    && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime \
    && "date" \
    && printf '[PHP]\ndate.timezone = "Europe/Warsaw"\n' > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/tzone.ini

#RUN usermod -aG docker $USER
#COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
#RUN chmod -R 766 /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
#CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Comment: Same problem here, with a docker php:8.2.13-fpm and symfony 6.2. The docker is running on an Ubuntu 22.04.3

Comment: I have the same problem since few days: docker, nginx, php:8.1.26 and symfony 6.0. I've checked the docker logs and in my case it seems that SIGSEGV error on the PHP container is related to the following error on the MySQL container: `Aborted connection 226 to db: 'database_name' user: 'root' host: '172.16.31.8' (Got an error reading communication packets)`. Maybe it will be some hint

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Because the message stated that core dump has been created, I wanted to check what's inside. In order to have some meaningful backtrace in `gdb`, I needed to recompile my PHP with `--enable-debug` option (according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php it adds debugging symbols), so I did it:

1. I copied https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/50c8b1ceaefdaebc4df51322f1e0dc149a1cda15/8.1/alpine3.19/fpm/Dockerfile together with all `docker-php-...` files
2. Modified it according to the description from https://500.keboola.com/building-a-php-7-4-21-docker-image-with-support-for-gdb-debugger/
3. Added changes from my original Dockerfile at the end of the created file

Surprisingly, after running my app again using new PHP build, the error is not occurring anymore. So I recompiled it once again without the flag, and the error is back again. Obviously, without the `--enable-debug` flag, no debugging symbols can be loaded, but even without them, there may be something interesting in core dump:

```
#0  zend_string_equal_content (s2=0x206e727574657220, s1=0x7f5eb1e6e2d0) at /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_string.h:357
357     return ZSTR_LEN(s1) == ZSTR_LEN(s2) && zend_string_equal_val(s1, s2);
```

Anyway, it seems that in my case **building PHP with --enable-debug flag resolves the problem**, so it could be possibly used as a temporary workaround in your cases - unless someone will find better solution.